# Creating dynamic TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-recyclerview, dynamic-allocation

Now I'm developing Android application by Android Studio.
I have some problem with dynamic allocation of TextView.
I am using RecyclerView to Implement showing list of items.
each ViewHolder item of RecyclerView should have ArrayList of TextView.
The size of ArrayList can be different in each ViewHolder item because 
it receives data from node.js server. So I want to assign TextView in ViewHolder
by dynamic allocation. the problem is when I create the TextView and addView to the LinearLayout in onBindViewHolder. It doesn't work. but the other assignment of Views except dynamic TextViews work. 
I would be very glad if you could help me.

Since I receive the data from Server in Array of JSON Array type,
RecyclerView's Adapter's data type is ArrayList of ArrayList

and here goes my code

```
public class PlayUpSitterListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayUpSitterListAdapter.PlayUpListViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<PlayupSitter>> playUpList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<PlayupSitter> playUp = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context ctx;

    public PlayUpSitterListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ArrayList<PlayupSitter>> playUpList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        for(int i=0; i < playUpList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(playUpList.get(i).get(0).play_paid == 0)
            {
                this.playUpList.add(playUpList.get(i));
            }
            else
            {
                this.playUpList.add(playUpList.get(i));
            }
        }
        /*
    for(int i =0; i<playUpList.size(); i++) {
        DynamicPlayUpTextView dynamicPlayUpTextView = new DynamicPlayUpTextView(ctx, "");
        holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.add(dynamicPlayUpTextView);
    }
    */
    }

    public void setPlayUpList(ArrayList<ArrayList<PlayupSitter>> playUpList) {

        for(int i=0; i < playUpList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(playUpList.get(i).get(0).play_paid ==0)
            {
                this.playUpList.add(playUpList.get(i));
            }
            else 
            {
                this.playUpList.add(playUpList.get(i));
            }
        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<PlayupSitter> getItem(int position) {
        return (playUpList != null && (0 <= position && position < playUpList.size())) ? playUpList.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public PlayUpListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup sitter, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(sitter.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.item_play_up_sitter, sitter, false);
        return new PlayUpListViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlayUpListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ArrayList<PlayupSitter> playUp = playUpList.get(position);

        String temp;
        int vh_paytotal=0;

        for(int i=0; i< playUp.size(); i++) {

            temp = getmessage(playUp.get(i).play_date, playUp.get(i).sitter_rank, playUp.get(i).play_hour);
            DynamicPlayUpTextView dynamicPlayUpTextView = new DynamicPlayUpTextView(ctx, temp);
            holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.add(i, dynamicPlayUpTextView);

            holder.dynamicLL.addView(holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.get(i).buildDynamicPlayUpTextView());


            if(playUp.get(i).sitter_rank == "A")
            {
                vh_paytotal += 13000 * playUp.get(i).play_hour;
            }
            else if (playUp.get(i).sitter_rank == "B")
            {
                vh_paytotal += 10000 * playUp.get(i).play_hour;
            }
            else{
                vh_paytotal += 8000 * playUp.get(i).play_hour;
            }
        }
        if (playUpList.get(position).get(0).play_paid == 1) {

            holder.imgGrayBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgGrayBackground.setClickable(false);
        } else {
            holder.imgGrayBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgGrayBackground.setClickable(true);
        }

        holder.pay_total.setText(vh_paytotal + "원");

    }

    private String getmessage(String play_date, String sitter_rank, int play_hour) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, play_date + "      12000(" + sitter_rank +"등급) X"+play_hour + " = "+ play_hour * 12000+"원", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return play_date + "      12000(" + sitter_rank +"등급) X"+play_hour + " = "+ play_hour * 12000+"원";
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (playUpList != null) ? playUpList.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class PlayUpListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ArrayList<DynamicPlayUpTextView> dynamictextViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        ImageView imgGrayBackground;
        ImageView imgLine;
        LinearLayout dynamicLL;

        TextView txtPlayUp_TP;
        TextView pay_total;

        DynamicPlayUpTextView ddd;

        public  PlayUpListViewHolder(View itemView)  {
            super(itemView);

            dynamicLL = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_dynamic_play_up_sitter);
            imgGrayBackground = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grayBackground_playUp_Sitter);
            imgLine = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_line_play_up_sitter);
            pay_total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayUp_TotalPay);
            txtPlayUp_TP = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlayUp_TP);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to set LayoutParams before adding your ArrayList.
So let's add this below:

```
dynamicPlayUpTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

between:

```
        DynamicPlayUpTextView dynamicPlayUpTextView = new DynamicPlayUpTextView(ctx, temp);
        holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.add(i, dynamicPlayUpTextView);
```

Comment: I'd already set LayoutParams in DynamicPlayUpTextView Constructor.

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
txtLocationItem.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 


like this.

Comment: Than let's add function to PlayUpListViewHolder like 'addview(TextView tv){ dynamicLL.addView(tv); }' and use it in loop after added ArrayList

Comment: I declared the function addview as you said in PlayUpListViewHolder Class and used it in onBindViewHolder loop after added to ArrayList. but it does not work :( what is the difference between holder.dynamicLL.addView(holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.get(i).buildDynamicPlayUpTextView()); and  holder.addview(holder.dynamictextViewArrayList.get(i).buildDynamicPlayUpTextView()); ??

Comment: I solved this problem setting text color black. your solutions are right. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't set my TextColor. It was actually worked but I was confused since it's default color was white, same to the background color. It was my fault. Closing this Issue